# HTML page consuming lots of RAM

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Memory usage is high, but nothing is shown. The page keeps loading.

```html
<html>
<title>Array</title>
<body onload="myFunction()">
  <center>
    <p id="demo">This is an array</p>
  </center>
  <script>
    var globe;
    var i = 0;

    function myFunction() {
      var sl = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "d", "e", "f"];
      for (i = 0; i < 7; i) {
        globe = sl[i];
        setTimeout(pk, 50);
      }
    }

    function pk() {
      document.write(globe);
      i++;
      myFunction();
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Can someone please explain to me, what's really happening in this script?

Answer (score 2):

Informally, you can think of all your js code being executed on a single thread. What setTimeout(f,n) does is to execute function f when at least n milliseconds have passed, and that thread is idle. Since myFunction never returns, as it does not increment i internally, the thread never becomes idle, and pk is never called. The memory is being consumed by a huge amount of scheduled calls.

When you fix this, remember that you also have mutual recursion between pk and myFunction, which will also overload your browser with a huge number of calls.

Answer (score 1):

Simple `HTML` never use lot of amount of `RAM`, if it's happen you must be sure there is a `JavaScript` code for implementing interaction that made this issue.

For your special code your problem is definitely your `JavaScript` code, your `for` loop is wrote badly. see:

```
for(i = 0;i < 7;i) // the last i must be i++
{
   globe = sl[i];
   setTimeout(pk,50);
}
```

With third `i` your loop act infinitely, so in third section you must declare step, the `i++`, change your code and you will see it works awesome.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Basically, to extrapolate a little bit on the answers above, the variable inside the loop never gets incremented, so therefore the loop will run indefinitely.

You are incrementing `i` in your `pk()` function, but that function never runs, as your app stalls on the infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

Adding i++ in loop solves the problem.

You can even use

```
for (items in sl){
    //whatever code you want
}
```

This for ... in loop gives you benefit that you can transverse array of any size